# Calling bash script with redirection from Java

Tags: java, bash, shell, logging, redirect

I have a bash shell script that executes a bunch of commands and redirects the command outputs to log files using `>`. If I call the shell script from Java using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh shellscript.sh");`, the shell script gets executed but the log files don't get written! Why? And how do I make it work?

**EDIT:**
Okay so what I'm trying to do is a little different. Your code works fine. But now redirection inside the Java program is not working. In the sample program below, the log file is not written!

```
$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello there"
echo "Hello there 2"


$ cat RunScript.java 
public class RunScript {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        int i = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /home/gpx/script.sh >> log").waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exit code : " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The redirects that you are writing to - are they writing to absolute file paths or relative file pahts?

If its relative, then they would (probably) be relative to the work directory - so check that.

A SAMPLE TEST I DID THAT SHOWS ABSOLUTE PATHS WILL WORK

```
$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello there"
echo "Hello there 2" >> /Users/madhurt/test/log

exit 2

$ cat RunScript.java 
public class RunScript {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        int i = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /Users/madhurt/test/script.sh").waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exit code : " + i);
    }
}
$ pwd
/Users/madhurt/test
$ ls -lrt 
total 24
-rwxr-xr-x  1 madhurt  staff   87 Dec  6 18:28 script.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 madhurt  staff  214 Dec  6 18:32 RunScript.java
-rw-r--r--  1 madhurt  staff  907 Dec  6 18:32 RunScript.class
$ java RunScript
Exit code : 2
$ ls -lrt 
total 32
-rwxr-xr-x  1 madhurt  staff   87 Dec  6 18:28 script.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 madhurt  staff  214 Dec  6 18:32 RunScript.java
-rw-r--r--  1 madhurt  staff  907 Dec  6 18:32 RunScript.class
-rw-r--r--  1 madhurt  staff   14 Dec  6 18:33 log
$ cat log 
Hello there 2
$
```

Comment: They are relative. We simply write something like `cat file.txt >> log.txt`. We've checked for that already!

Comment: well if they are relative, then they would be written to a location, relative to the working directory of the java process that you run. So you should check for the log files relative to the java process' working directory. I would not recommend that though - logs files should be written to absolute location, which must be configurable.

Comment: Okay, just rewrote them using absolute path. Didn't help!

Comment: That's strange, can you update the question with a snippet of your log redirect code?

Comment: Also, I hope you are sure that the script is "actually" running. I mean its not that the Runtime process is just throwing out an exception or returning in an error?

Comment: No, it does run, without throwing any error. In fact, it executes the shell script, which executes all the echo statements inside it perfectly. It is the redirection that is not working!

Comment: I've tried creating a simple test program (edited in my answer) and it works. So there is something in the code you are writing that's not correct. I cannot know what that is until I see the code.

Answer (score 0):

My Java-knowledge is scant, but it's my understanding that you have to write:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh shellscript.sh").waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have write permissions to the path you are appending the log too. If you run this app within a container, it will most likely use that user's id. Try to write the file in `/tmp/` and see if it appears there.